# Can you grow a fig tree in full shade?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, bonsai, figs

About 3 weeks ago I propagated a cutting from a fig tree in water. It is growing roots and almost ready to plant.

I have a nice spot for it but it will (at best) receive 1-2 hours of direct morning sun during summer. The rest of the year its pretty bright but no direct sunlight.

I am aware that it may not carry fruits but will it survive?

I plan to grow it as a bonsai, if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, give it a go. One of the gardens I look after has a fig growing in the heavy shade of a sycamore. In the past it's fruited, but not for the past few years as the shade cast by the sycamore has increased. I think this is one of those things you just need to try.

Answer (score 3):

I think it will survive. I saw a fig grow on a shadow place: a wall in south-west, and a tall building on south/south-east. Maybe on summer it had 3-4 hours sun, but else it was in a dark place.

Just it will not grow well, possibly you will have few fig per year, but I'm not sure if it will grow like a tree or just like a shrub (2-5 meter tall, but without a main trunk).

Answer (score 2):

It will grow and survive, but it will produce minimal if any edible fruit.  I planted 3 figs at a new house where I didn't pay attention to how much sun that spot received and the fruit they produce only grows as big as a grape and they are not edible.  But, the plants are green, full of beautiful leaves.  I live in Ohio and they freeze but come back every spring.